# Valid approach for generic operators

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, operator-keyword

I have a class `Gen<T>` and I want to make it possible to compare them. The following code cannot be compiled, because the == cannot be applied to Parent and Child. Is there a way to make this comparison possible, or is this bad practice in general?

```
public class Parent{
    public int x;
}

public class Child:Parent{}

public class Gen<T> 
    where T : Parent 
{
    public T variable;
}

public static class Gen
{
    public static bool operator ==(Gen<Parent> left, Gen<Parent> right){
        if (left.variable.x == right.variable.x)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}

public void Test()
{
    Gen<Parent> foo = new Gen<Parent>();
    Gen<Child> bar = new Gen<Child>();

    if (foo == bar)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The full context is the following:

1. `Gen<T>` equals `ColorSet<T>` where T:Color
2. Parent equals Color
3. Child is a class that stores additional information for a color, which are not necessary for every Color objects.

I want to access every `Color` through the `ColorSet<T>` class, which looks like this:

```
public class ColorSet<T> where T : Color
{
     private T blue;
     private T red;
     private T green;

     public ColorSet()
     {
         Red = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new object[] { });
         Red.Name = Values.Res.get("red");
         Blue = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new object[] { });
         Blue.Name = Values.Res.get("blue");
         Green = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new object[] { });
         Green.Name = Values.Res.get("green");
     }
}
```

But sometimes I need `ColorSet<Color>` and sometimes `ColorSet<Child>` for the additional information. And it should be possible to compare `ColorSet<Color>` with `ColorSet<Child>` because they have the most relevant information in common.

Comment: I don't know of a way of doing it - the operators themselves can't be generic - but I can't remember ever wanting to do anything like this, either. I would write a straightforward method instead, to be honest.

Comment: @JonSkeet You mean a method like: public static bool compare(Gen<Parent> one, Gen<Child> two){...}

Comment: Yes, although following normal naming conventions. Or make it an extension method. Or make it an instance method in `Gen<T>`. But even with all of those, it's still a slightly odd thing to do - comparing values of two different types for equality is rarely a good idea. What's the real context here?

Comment: @JonSkeet thank you for your response. I will considering your advice. I edited the question and explained the full context. If you need more information let me know.

Comment: In that case, I'd probably add something like `ColorEquals` to `ColorSet`, documenting carefully that it's only comparing them for base `Color` values. That method could then be generic, accepting a `ColorSet<TOther>`.

Comment: I don't really see the advantage of having `ColorSet<T>` generic here. I may be overlooking something, but I would probably simply make it `ColorSet`, and make its constructor take a `Type` argument. Since you'd then not have any generic type, you would then be able to define operators without any problems.

Comment: Normally I would say that if @JonSkeet can't do it, it can't be done. But I suspect you could do this by constructing a `Expression<Func<T, T, bool>>` using the `Expression.Equal` static function. However I am not sure what the LinqToObject provider will translate that to.

Comment: @Aron: How would an expression tree help to make `if (foo == bar)` compile?

Comment: @JonSkeet It wouldn't. But you can produce a `Func<T, T, bool>` which has the same effect hopefully....>_< I am pretty sure I am wrong since I am arguing with you....

Comment: @Aron: It won't have the same effect in that you'd need to change the calling code... and if you're going to change the calling code, you can just introduce a named method instead, without resorting to expression trees. I still just don't see how expression trees would help...

Comment: Thanks for all responses, I am looking into everyone, but first a question to @hvd : Can you give a short example of this constructor? I don't insist on this generic class, so  your approach seems to be suitable for me.

Comment: @jasdefer I was thinking simply `public ColorSet(Type type) { ... Red = (Color)Activator.CreateInstance(type, new object[] { }); ... }` (don't forget error checking: `type` needs to be non-null and derive from `Color`, in addition to your current requirement of having a public constructor), and call it like `new ColorSet(typeof(ExtendedColor))`. But if you do anything with the type that needs to be visible at compile-time, such as a property or function that returns `T`, where you cannot simply return `Color` instead, that wouldn't work.

Comment: @hvd Ah okay, I think this is nice. Creating a new ColorSet would look like: '...= new ColorSet(typeof(Color));'? But than the compiler would not show an error if the argument is not of type 'Color' or any children, am i right? Of course, I would check inside the constructor if the type is valid, but this is only possible during run time. I am sorry, I am not familiar with all of this.

Comment: @jasdefer Yes, exactly. You could even go one step further and make a generic `public static ColorSet FromType<T>() where T : Color { return new ColorSet(typeof(T)); }`, and then instead of `new ColorSet(typeof(ExtendedColor))`, you'd write `ColorSet.FromType<ExtendedColor>()`, which does allow the compiler to perform compile-time checks.

Comment: @hvd okay, and than I could make the constructor private, so that it is not possible to create a new instance in the regular way? Okay this is nice. It is maybe a little bit strange to create a new object like this, but it would solve my problem. What do the others say to this approach? I will take a look at the other solutions, before implementing this.

Comment: @jasdefer Yes, that's possible. I had just expanded a bit more and since it's getting quite long, put it into an answer. You can decide whether you want to use it; I won't take offence if you don't. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(expanding from the comments) A generic class doesn't seem to be necessary. A valid approach for getting operators to work for generic types is to re-work the types so that they're no longer generic.

`ColorSet` could be defined as

```
public class ColorSet {
  private Color red;
  private Color green;
  private Color blue;

  protected ColorSet(Type type) {
    red = (Color)Activator.CreateType(type);
    red.Name = Values.Res.get("red");
    green = (Color)Activator.CreateType(type);
    green.Name = Values.Res.get("red");
    blue = (Color)Activator.CreateType(type);
    blue.Name = Values.Res.get("red");
  }

  public static ColorSet FromType<T>() where T : Color {
    return new ColorSet(typeof(T));
  }
}
```

Instead of `new ColorSet<ExtendedColor>()`, you would now call `ColorSet.FromType<ExtendedColor>()`.

This works so long as you don't actually need to use your `T` outside of your constructor.

If you had, for instance, a

```
public T Red { get { return red; } }
```

property, you would need to change that to a

```
public Color Red { get { return red; } }
```

property.

However, if you have anything like that, and you do want to keep the generic type, you can then put that in a derived generic class:

```
public class ColorSet<T> : ColorSet where T : Color {
  public ColorSet<T>() : base(typeof(T)) { }
  public new T Red { get { return (T)base.Red; } }
}
```

which still only needs operators for the base non-generic `ColorSet` class.

Comment: I think this is my solution. Thank you very much. The only (very very small)  disadvantage of this approach is, that the creation of a new `ColorSet` object is a little bit different than usual. But this is more than acceptable.

Comment: @jasdefer Glad it helped, but I think you missed the end of my answer, which is something that wasn't in the comments on your question: you can create a `ColorSet<T>` generic class which derives from the non-generic `ColorSet` class, and does have a public constructor and allows construction in the form you're already used to.

Comment: Ah yes you are right. I thought you meant this if I really need a `public T Red...` property. But it also enables another form of initiating a new object. I think I wont need this, so creating this child class only for initiating purposes is not necessary. Thank you again.

Comment: I just noticed: Should it be `public new T Red { get { return (T)base.Red; } }` with an additional `new`?

Comment: @jasdefer It's not strictly required, but it is highly recommendable. Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

To come back to your original question/sample: this is not beautifull but it works (for your example - i only tested it with two)
It uses reflection though so I'm not that happy with it:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int x;

    public Parent (int x)
    {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object o)
    {
        var p = o as Parent;
        if (object.Equals(p, null))
            return false;

        return this.x == p.x;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return x;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Parent a, Parent b)
    {
        return a.Equals (b);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Parent a, Parent b)
    {
        return !(a == b);
    }

}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public Child (int x)
        : base(x)
    {

    }
}

public class Gen<T> 
    where T : Parent 
{
    public T variable;

    public Gen (T x)
    {
        this.variable = x;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object o)
    {
        if (object.Equal(o, null)) return false;

        // CAUTION: VERY DIRTY - just a quick reply to hvd - should check/remove this with test cases!
        try
        {
           var oT = o.GetType ().GetGenericTypeDefinition ();
           var tT = this.GetType ().GetGenericTypeDefinition ();
           if (tT != oT)
               return false;

           // for example this:
           // var oVar = o.GetType().GetField ("variable").GetValue (o);
           // should really be
           var varField = o.GetType().GetField("variable");
           if (varField == null) return;
           var oVar = varField.GetValue(o);

           if (object.Equals(oVar, null)) 
              return object.Equals(this.variable, null);

           return this.variable.Equals (oVar);
         } catch { return false; }
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return variable.GetHashCode();
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Gen<T> a, object b)
    {
        return a.Equals (b);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Gen<T> a, object b)
    {
        return !(a == b);
    }

}
```

Here is yours and another example:

```
public static void Test()
{
    Gen<Parent> foo = new Gen<Parent>(new Parent(5));
    Gen<Child> bar = new Gen<Child>(new Child(5));
    Gen<Child> bas = new Gen<Child>(new Child(6));

    if (foo == bar)
        Console.WriteLine ("equal");
    else
        Console.WriteLine ("not-equal");

    if (foo == bas)
        Console.WriteLine ("equal");
    else
        Console.WriteLine ("not-equal");
}
```

btw: you don't really need the (==) and (!=) on the `Parent` class - but well it does not hurt

Comment: The approach may be workable (though I personally wouldn't go for it), but there are quite a number of cases that throw an exception in your form that really shouldn't. `o` could be `null`. `o` could have a non-generic type. `o` could have a member `variable` that's `null`. `this.variable` could also be `null` in your code, though not in the OP's case with `ColorSet`.

Comment: yes all true - but you can work all this out if you really want (indeed a very dirty fix would be to wrap the thing into a `try`-`catch` - and this is surely not the *prefered* solution (this will surely come from **Jon**) - but for the given example it does work ... but I guess you have a good point

Answer (score 0):

```
public class IGen<out T> 
    where T : Parent 
{
    T Variable{ get; }
}

public class Gen<T>
    : IGen<T>
    where T : Parent 
{
    public T Variable {get;set;}

    private static Func<T, T, bool> _equal;

    static Gen()
    {
        var left = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var right = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var body = Expression.Equal(left, right);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T, bool>>(body, left, right);
        _equal = lambda.Compile();
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Gen<T> left, Gen<T> right)
    {
        return _equal(left.Variable, right.Variable);
    }


    public static bool operator ==(Gen<T> left, IGen<T> right)
    {
        return _equal(left.Variable, right.Variable);
    }


    public static bool operator ==(IGen<T> left, Gen<T> right)
    {
        return _equal(left.Variable, right.Variable);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with expressions, but does this work like this: If a new `Gen<T>` is created, the new method _equal is created, which compares to objects of type T. But my compiler is still complaining that `if (foo == bar)` is not valid, because `==` cannot be applied to  `Gen<Parent>` and `Gen<Child>`. But maybe I did some mistakes, because I cannot find the Expression (should I be using `System.Linq.Expressions`? but than `Arguement` cannot be found)

Comment: @jasdefer My bad. Was doing it from memory. `Argument` was actually `Parameter`.

Comment: No problem and thanks for your response. But using this, I still get the problem, that `foo == bar` does not work because `==` cannot be applied to `Gen<Parent>`and `Gen<Child>` if I did not make another mistake.

Comment: I am not sure what this is, but is it the same reason as in my initial question? But thank you very much for your afford!

Comment: @jasdefer The issue is that `T` on the left != `T` on the right.

Comment: Okay, I saw the same problem than, but did not know that this is the name of the problem. I tried once to solve it with a `<T,U> where T:Parent where U:Parent` approach, but this was a bad idea too.